# Angular ERROR in : No provider for NgControl

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I'm creating a component implementing ControlValueAccessor to be used in a Reactive Form, it's just a wrapper of an input element with some pipe on it.

I've injected the NgControl in order to retrieve the valid/invalid state and propagate them to the inner input element.

When the input value is found in another input, it is invalid.

[Here is the Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/control-value-accessor-ngcontrol)

On Stackblitz is working fine, but when I to an *ng build --prod* it raises the error:

> ERROR in : No provider for NgControl ("[ERROR ->])

Do you see any problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hello you can add "@Optional" Decorator for your NgControl. It will use **null** if it cant find a provider. For more information look at: https://angular.io/api/core/Optional

In your Code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Self,Optional } from '@angular/core';

...
      constructor(
    @Self() @Optional() private controlContainer: NgControl
  ) {
    this.controlContainer.valueAccessor = this;
  }
```

Comment: oh so maybe it's null because i'm using the same component in another point the the code not wrapped by a form ?!

Comment: I tried this but the controlContailer returen a null, so i couldn't call valueAccessor of that. How to resolve that?

Comment: Thanks - this was exactly the problem that I was having and the `@Optional()` decorator resolved the issue. For clarity, this was not a problem using the regular `ng build` command, but it was a problem when running the production build using `ng build --prod`.