# What can be the reason for next error "No Provider for NGControl" in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

when I'm running command `ng build --prod` I get the error `ERROR in No provider for NgControl ("[ERROR ->]<multiselect></multiselect>")`, when running `ng build` or `ng serve` no errors shown.

That is code for `multiselect` component constructor, the `NgControl` injected as `@Optional`.
[image]

The component itself being used in one place, **inside the form component**:
[image]

The `multiselect` component has been created following that guide:  https://v7.material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control

I have already seen some similar questions:
[Angular ERROR in : No provider for NgControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276176/angular-error-in-no-provider-for-ngcontrol)
[ERROR in : No provider for NgControl Angular AOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886424/error-in-no-provider-for-ngcontrol-angular-aot)
...

And the advices collected:

1. Use `@Optional`
2. Ensure that component wrapped into the form

seems like everything should be ok, but not

Comment: Just checking, have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525588/5733111) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66857484/5733111)

Comment: @SanoopSurendran Thank you for help, yes have tried both, the issues still exists

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the angular 8 app, that was migrated from 7 version, where the same error has been exists.

I have created new empty angular 8 project with angular-cli, and tsconfig, I found some differences between angular 7 and angular 8, I have applied them to my project. Then error message changed to `annotationCIs is not a constructor`, and then I have googled https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15395

Finally the problem was that `Optional` was imported from `ag-grid` instead of `@angular/core`, I found some places with that wrong import, fixed them to

```
// were
import { Optional } from `ag-grid`;

// become
import { Optional } from `@angular/core`;
```

and that issue had been resolved.